# ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small - Convert Clob to varchar2

Tags: json, oracle, plsql, clob

Im getting this error while i trying to convert clob to varchar2 using an api.

The 'body' field that im trying to retrieve is clob, However i want to convert it to varchar2(1000).

Please advice why this error occurred :

```
       MERGE INTO XXX D
                 USING (
                       select  
                              v_ticket_id ticket_id,
                              json_ext.get_number(json(value(S)),'id') comment_id,
                              json_ext.get_number(json(value(S)),'author_id') author_id , 
                              DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(json_ext.get_string(json(value(S)),'body'),1000,1) body,
                              json_ext.get_string(json(value(S)),'via.channel')channel,
                              case when lower(json(value(S)).get('public').to_char()) = 'true' then 1 else 0 end  is_public,
                              to_date(replace(replace(json_ext.get_string(json(value(S)),'created_at'),'T',' '),'Z',null), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') created_at,
                              sysdate
                              FROM table(PKG.sf_retreive_data('RETREIVE').list_data) S) S

                ON (D.ticket_id = S.ticket_id and D.comment_id = S.comment_id)

                WHEN MATCHED THEN          
                      UPDATE SET   author_id = S.author_id,
                                   body = S.body,
                                   channel = S.channel,
                                   is_public = S.is_public,
                                   created_at = S.created_at, 
                                   bi_updated_time = sysdate

                WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN          
                      insert (ticket_id,comment_id,author_id ,body,channel,is_public,created_at,bi_updated_time)
                      values
                             (S.ticket_id,S.comment_id,S.author_id,S.body,S.channel,S.is_public,S.created_at,sysdate);
               commit;
```

And i get this error :
Error: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small

Comment: What is full exception stack? How big are the other get_string results - have you narrowed it down to the comment?

Comment: Incidentally, nothing to do with the error, but you don't need your `replace` calls; you can embed literals in the format mask: `to_date(json_ext.get_string(json(value(S)),'created_at'), 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"')`.

Comment: Does the `SELECT` from the `USING` clause execute successfully if you run it by itself (i.e. not as part of the `MERGE` statement above)? Also, please edit your question and include the definition of the `XXX` table. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting an Error "ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7567693/getting-an-error-ora-06502-pl-sql-numeric-or-value-error-character-string-bu)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the line :
                              DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(json_ext.get_string(json(value(S)),'body'),1000,1) body,

should has been inserted into varchar2(1000).

The function DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR wasn't working as should for this operation.
And the string was bigger than the CLOB data type due to special character sets (Json obj).

The solution:
insert into table(GTT) with clob column and then substr into varchar2 XXX table.